# jQuery injecting a new value to variable

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js:

```
var main = jQuery(this).parents('.top');    

main.find('.top_left').removeClass("s7").addClass("s4");
main.find('.top_right').removeClass("s5").addClass("s4");
```

There are three things that will be changed: `.find, .removeClass, .addClass`.

Is there a way to make this whole thing as a variable then just "inject" the values into each field as shown below?

```
var rhp_left = jQuery(this).parents('.top');    
var rhp_total= rhp_left.find(A).removeClass(B).addClass(C);
```

Then somehow put a new `A,B,C` value to it: `A = '.top_right'` Somthing like that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You could create a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) that takes 3 parameters.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. But it sounds like you just want to re-use the same code so @showdev suggestion of making a function will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a [JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) that accepts 3 parameters. Then call that function and pass it the desired values. You can configure the function to accept jQuery objects, selector strings, class names, etc.

For example:

> o = the object to act upon
>   f = the selector to find within the object
>   r = the class to remove
>   a = the class to add

```js
function alter(o, f, r, a) {
  jQuery(o).find(f).removeClass(r).addClass(a);
}

jQuery('#go_trigger').on('click', function() {
  alter('#item1', '.first_word', 'upper',   'blue');
  alter('#item2', 'input',       'small',   'red');
  alter('#item2', 'p.bgcolor',   'bgcolor', 'bold');
});
```

```css
.blue    { color: blue;}
.upper   { text-transform: uppercase;}
.bgcolor { background-color:grey;}
.bold    { font-weight: bold;}
.small   { font-size: .5em;}
.red     { color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item1">
  <span class="first_word upper">Hello</span>
  <span class="second_word upper">World</span>
</div>
<div id="item2">
  <input type="text" class="small" value="an input" />
  <p class="bgcolor">Testing...</p>
  <p>Unaffected.</p>
</div>

<button type="button" id="go_trigger">CLICK HERE</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think i understand javascript a bit more than before. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd extend the possibilities a little and offer an alternative approach which extends the jQuery prototype and adds the functionality as a plug-in:

```
// wrapping the plugin code in an Immediately-Invoked
// Function Expression ("IIFE"), so that the function
// is invoked when it's encountered rather than
// having to be called subsequently:
(function($) {

  // defining the name of the plugin 'findAndSwitchClasses',
  // and allowing user-supplied arguments to the plugin
  // the 'opts' variable:
  $.fn.findAndSwitchClasses = function(opts) {

    // defining the default settings:
    var settings = $.extend({
      'descendantSelector': '.top_left',
      'classToRemove': 's7',
      'classToAdd': 's4'

    // updating the defaults - using $.extend() - to
    // override the defaults with user-supplied
    // arguments:
    }, opts);

    // returning the collection supplied to the plugin,
    // 'this', here, is the jQuery collection:
    return this.each(function() {

      // this is a DOM Node inside the each(),
      // wrapping that Node with jQuery to
      // allow jQuery methods to be called:
      $(this)

        // finding the descendant elements
        // matching the supplied selector:
        .find(settings.descendantSelector)

        // removing the supplied class:
        .removeClass(settings.classToRemove)

        // adding the supplied class:
        .addClass(settings.classToAdd);
    });
  };

// passing jQuery into the function, allowing the
// plugin to make use of the $ alias (for brevity):
})(jQuery)

// using the defaults:
$('#main').findAndSwitchClasses();

// using alternative settings to
// override the defaults:
$('#main').findAndSwitchClasses({
  'descendantSelector': '.top_right',
  'classToRemove': 's5'
});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.findAndSwitchClasses = function(opts) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      'descendantSelector': '.top_left',
      'classToRemove': 's7',
      'classToAdd': 's4'
    }, opts);

    return this.each(function() {
      $(this)
        .find(settings.descendantSelector)
        .removeClass(settings.classToRemove)
        .addClass(settings.classToAdd);
    });
  };
})(jQuery)

$('#main').findAndSwitchClasses();

$('#main').findAndSwitchClasses({
  'descendantSelector': '.top_right',
  'classToRemove': 's5'
});
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
#main div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
.s4 {
  border-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="top_left s7">

  </div>
  <div class="top_right s5">

  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ov2v5odh/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: This is really insightful. Thank you.  This seems complicated at first but reading it through, I am understanding the logic and how to utilize it. Once again, really appreciate it! =)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped in some small way! :)

Comment: Haha, it was an approach that I never thought about and really helped me! =) Thanks David!